# Difference between the various joins in SQL

Tags: mysql, join

I am confused with `natural join`, `theta join` and `inner join` because all of them tend to give the same results for the schema given below.

By Definition:

> The natural join forms a Cartesian product of its two arguments, performs a selection forcing equality on those attributes that appear in both relation schema.
>
> The theta join is an extension to the natural join operation that allows us to combine a selection and Cartesian product in a single operation
>
> The inner join computes the theta join of the two relations with the given join condition.

Consider the schema:

```
mysql> select * from loan;
+---------+-------------+--------+
| loan_id | branch_name | amount |
+---------+-------------+--------+
| L11     | Round Hill  |    900 |
| L14     | Downtown    |   1500 |
| L15     | Perryridge  |   1500 |
| L16     | Perryridge  |   1300 |
| L17     | Downtown    |   1000 |
| L23     | Redwood     |   2000 |
| L93     | Mianus      |    500 |
+---------+-------------+--------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from borrower;
+---------------+---------+
| customer_name | loan_id |
+---------------+---------+
| Adams         | L16     |
| Curry         | L93     |
| Hayes         | L15     |
| Jackson       | L14     |
| Jones         | L17     |
| Smith         | L11     |
| Smith         | L23     |
| Williams      | L17     |
| Adams         | L19     |
| Adams         | L15     |
| Jones         | L15     |
| Williams      | L23     |
+---------------+---------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Natual Join**

```
mysql> select * from loan l, borrower b where l.loan_id=b.loan_id;
+---------+-------------+--------+---------------+---------+
| loan_id | branch_name | amount | customer_name | loan_id |
+---------+-------------+--------+---------------+---------+
| L16     | Perryridge  |   1300 | Adams         | L16     |
| L93     | Mianus      |    500 | Curry         | L93     |
| L15     | Perryridge  |   1500 | Hayes         | L15     |
| L14     | Downtown    |   1500 | Jackson       | L14     |
| L17     | Downtown    |   1000 | Jones         | L17     |
| L11     | Round Hill  |    900 | Smith         | L11     |
| L23     | Redwood     |   2000 | Smith         | L23     |
| L17     | Downtown    |   1000 | Williams      | L17     |
| L15     | Perryridge  |   1500 | Adams         | L15     |
| L15     | Perryridge  |   1500 | Jones         | L15     |
| L23     | Redwood     |   2000 | Williams      | L23     |
+---------+-------------+--------+---------------+---------+
11 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

**Theta Join**

```
mysql> select * from loan l join borrower b on l.loan_id=b.loan_id;
+---------+-------------+--------+---------------+---------+
| loan_id | branch_name | amount | customer_name | loan_id |
+---------+-------------+--------+---------------+---------+
| L16     | Perryridge  |   1300 | Adams         | L16     |
| L93     | Mianus      |    500 | Curry         | L93     |
| L15     | Perryridge  |   1500 | Hayes         | L15     |
| L14     | Downtown    |   1500 | Jackson       | L14     |
| L17     | Downtown    |   1000 | Jones         | L17     |
| L11     | Round Hill  |    900 | Smith         | L11     |
| L23     | Redwood     |   2000 | Smith         | L23     |
| L17     | Downtown    |   1000 | Williams      | L17     |
| L15     | Perryridge  |   1500 | Adams         | L15     |
| L15     | Perryridge  |   1500 | Jones         | L15     |
| L23     | Redwood     |   2000 | Williams      | L23     |
+---------+-------------+--------+---------------+---------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Inner Join**

```
mysql> select * from loan l inner join borrower b on l.loan_id=b.loan_id;
+---------+-------------+--------+---------------+---------+
| loan_id | branch_name | amount | customer_name | loan_id |
+---------+-------------+--------+---------------+---------+
| L16     | Perryridge  |   1300 | Adams         | L16     |
| L93     | Mianus      |    500 | Curry         | L93     |
| L15     | Perryridge  |   1500 | Hayes         | L15     |
| L14     | Downtown    |   1500 | Jackson       | L14     |
| L17     | Downtown    |   1000 | Jones         | L17     |
| L11     | Round Hill  |    900 | Smith         | L11     |
| L23     | Redwood     |   2000 | Smith         | L23     |
| L17     | Downtown    |   1000 | Williams      | L17     |
| L15     | Perryridge  |   1500 | Adams         | L15     |
| L15     | Perryridge  |   1500 | Jones         | L15     |
| L23     | Redwood     |   2000 | Williams      | L23     |
+---------+-------------+--------+---------------+---------+
11 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

All the queries return the same result. What is the difference between them?

Comment: The difference is just in the syntax. If you do explain extended and show warnings (a way to see how exactly optimizer runs a query) all these queries are rewritten to the same query.

Comment: No reason to be confused. In MySQL, those three queries are *identical*. There's no difference, aside from using old-school comma syntax for a join operation, using the (newer) `JOIN` keyword, the inclusion of the `INNER` keyword which has no influence, or whether the predicate is specified in the `ON` clause or `WHERE` clause. Aside from some superficial syntax changes, the three statements are *identical*. We expect all three statements to return the same result.

Answer (score 2):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra

Provides the best explanation of the different joins you're trying to understand.

The natural join is the most basic kind of joins between two sets. The primary key and corresponding foreign key of the tuples from two sets are compared for equality to derive the joined set of tuples.

As user @amalamalpm pointed out:

> a theta join allows for arbitrary comparison relationships.

Because the theta join allows for arbitrary comparisons, the natural join can be thought of as a subset of the theta join.

An inner join is the sql implementation of the theta join, and thus is used whenever the natural join is used.

**Note**: In mysql, you can do the following to get a natural join. This requires fewer characters and is favoured by people who are lazy (like I am).

```
select * from loan natural join borrower
```

This will also remove the duplicate field `loan_id` which exists in both sets (i.e. only show once in the result-set).

The three ways you write your query are all trying to get the same result-set.

You're doing a natural join >> which is a subset of a theta join >> which is inner join in sql parlance.

So mysql gives you the same result-set. *I haven't run `explain extended` on them so I can't vouch for this,* but I'd guess mysql executes the queries identically as well.

Comment: @spencer7593, while the example queries provided by the OP are identical, there is a conceptual difference between natural join, equi join, theta join in relational algebra theory, and *inner join*, which is just sql-speak.

Answer (score 1):

- In natural join the name and domain of joining attribute must be same.
- In inner join only domain of joining attribute needs to be same
- A theta join allows for arbitrary comparison relationships (such as
  ≥).

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, all three of these queries are identical.

```
  select * from loan l, borrower b where l.loan_id=b.loan_id;

  select * from loan l join borrower b on l.loan_id=b.loan_id;

  select * from loan l inner join borrower b on l.loan_id=b.loan_id;
```

In practice, each of these queries are **equi-joins**.

---

"In theory, there's no difference between theory and practice. In practice, there is"

Applying theoretical labels such as "natural", "theta" and "inner" doesn't change anything about the fact that all three of those statements are identical. All three of the statements do the same thing.

The first statement is just using the old-school comma syntax for a join operation. The comma in that first statement is equivalent to the `JOIN` keyword.

In MySQL `INNER JOIN` is synonymous with `JOIN`. That is, the addition or removal of the keyword `INNER` has no influence.

And a predicate is a predicate is a predicate. The rows being returned have to satisfy the condition, it doesn't matter whether the condition is specified in an `ON` clause or a `WHERE` clause (in the case of an inner join).